# Polymer grid with fixed rows and cols

Tags: css, polymer, grid-layout

For an application that uses [Polymer](http://www.polymer-project.org) I need a 3x3 grid. It does not have to be responsive since it should always display on a device with a certain screen. Currently this is how my grid looks:

```
<div flex style="height: calc(100%/3);" horizontal layout flex>
  <div flex style="height: 100%;">content</div>
  <div flex style="height: 100%;">content</div>
  <div flex style="height: 100%;">content</div>
</div>
<div flex style="height: calc(100%/3);" horizontal layout flex>
  <div flex style="height: 100%;">content</div>
  <div flex style="height: 100%;">content</div>
  <div flex style="height: 100%;">content</div>
</div>
<div flex style="height: calc(100%/3);" horizontal layout flex>
  <div flex style="height: 100%;">content</div>
  <div flex style="height: 100%;">content</div>
  <div flex style="height: 100%;">content</div>
</div>
```

Now, I need to populate this with content from an object. I know how I can easily insert an array of 3 elements into one of the rows, but I don't know how to populate all 9 content-areas with an array of 9 elements.

```
<div flex style="height: calc(100%/3);" horizontal layout flex>
  <template repeat="{{category in mainCategories }}">
    <div flex style="height: 100%; background-color: {{category.color}};">{{category.text}}</div>
  </template>
</div>
```

And this is what the object looks like (exactly 3 elements, otherwise it would mess things up):

```
Polymer('my-app', {
  mainCategories: [
    {
      "text" : "Cat 1",
      "color" : "red"
    },{
      "text" : "Cat 2 ",
      "color" : "green"
    },{
      "text" : "Cat 3",
      "color" : "yellow"
    }
  ]
});
```

But I want this `mainCategories` object to be exactly 9 elements long and I want to populate the grid with these values. Is this possible with the current setup, or should I not use a grid-system like this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A non-responsive grid layout is not what polymer was designed for, but there *is* a custom polymer component you can use here:

https://github.com/Polymer/core-layout-grid

This is a core component that can be used either directly or inherited by a custom component of your own creation. The Demo.Html shows an example of a control crated from the Core-Grid.

Comment: Be careful, this is element was deprecated at 0.5 it seems.
[link](https://www.polymer-project.org/0.5/docs/elements/core-layout-grid.html)

Comment: Unfortunately this answer is outdated as .42 was the newest release at the time. If you find a better solution be certain to post it :)